# Angular 2 dynamically create html tag

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there a way to dynamically create a html tag in components template?

Something like this

```
template:`<{{custom_tag}} [info]="info"></{{custom_tag}}>`
...
this.custom_tag="example";
this.info={};
```

Generated html will be something like this

```
<example info="..."></example>
```

Comment: By custom html tag you actually mean a component? Is this question about dynamic components?

Comment: @PeterMatisko yes. that tag will be a component

Comment: I was solving a similar problem. Please check my question and answer, it might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42215288/angular2-dynamic-components-in-content-received-by-api

You need to employ a compiler to add components dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I resolved with a directive to replace the tag:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42049947/7383715

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for the delay, but I'm adding my response:

Create a new component and now you can use that component selector tag itself inside wherever needed.

like;

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {}
```

Use selector as:

```
<app-example></app-example>
```

Pass parameters to the new component as:

```
 <app-example [param]="abc"></app-example>
```

This input param needs to be identified with the same identifier 'param' using ***@input()*** property.

Comment: That's not related to the question in any way. OP is asking about dynamic HTML-tags.